# Postgres/Rails Plural Issue in Queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, postgresql

I am having an issue with plurals in queries. What I need is a method in ruby or is the sql that can help me when I search. For example:

When I search "arrays"
I want it to return results for "array" as well.

Thanks

Comment: You're probably better off with a full text search system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [*word stemming*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).

You can't really do stemming of a language like English using a bunch of regular expressions, there are just too many exceptions. You need a big stemming dictionary.

PostgreSQL's full-text search offers such a dictionary, and I strongly recommend that you use full text search for this job:

```
regress=# WITH vals(a,b) AS (VALUES ('goose','geese'), ('query','queries'), ('arrays','array'))
SELECT to_tsquery(a), to_tsvector(b), to_tsquery(a) @@ to_tsvector(b) FROM vals;
 to_tsquery | to_tsvector | ?column? 
------------+-------------+----------
 'goos'     | 'gees':1    | f
 'queri'    | 'queri':1   | t
 'array'    | 'array':1   | t
(3 rows)
```

though you'll notice the stemming dictionary isn't perfect; I'd expect a search for "goose" to match "geese", but it didn't. You may need to enhance the dictionary. PostgreSQL's dictionary can also be [a bit over-enthusiastic about stemming at times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354167/prevent-stemming-of-proper-nouns-in-postgresql).

An alternative is to use a tool that's bigger and more easily customised, like Apache Solr.

Comment: Exactly! PostgreSQL full text search is way better than `LIKE` and it's built-in already. Try it and see how it works for your application. If it works well, great: you're done, and there's no extra moving parts. If it doesn't, deploy Sphinx or Solr -- both far more capable and frankly better at searching, but using a separate search server adds operational complexity. Sometimes PostgreSQL is the right choice, sometimes it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the dictionary, when using Postgres full text search, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852996/postgres-full-text-search-with-synonyms) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY).

But, as  mu is too short mentioned, you are probably better of using a more advanced tool. I prefer [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/), for this kind of thing.

Comment: No need to modify the dictionary just to handle plurals. Plenty of standard stemming dictionaries for different languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class.all(:conditions => ["attribute LIKE ?", "array%"])
```

That should do it, I've been working with Rails 2 for a while so there is prob a nicer way but will do the trick.

Comment: But what happens if you search for "geese"? Should searching for "the" find "thesaurus"?

Comment: depends how you want to set it up I guess, you could use the methods singluarize and pluralize on your search query and return both? What exactly are you wanting to achieve?